# Ajax Jquery update value in Mysql table and refresh value on page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Hi I am new to ajax and am having a hard time with something basic. I have a mysql table "users" that has user info including the balance they pledge to donate. I want to have a div that when clicked adds 10 to their balance and refreshes the balance which is displayed below. I have the following for the page.

```
<?php
    include_once 'login.php';
    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    mysql_select_db($db_database);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<script src ="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                $("#click").click(
                    function()
                    {
                        var ten = 10;
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url:  "updatebalance.php",
                                type: "post",
                                data: ten,
                                success: function(data) {

                                     document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = ""
                                     alert('it was successful');
                                 }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            });
 </script>


<html>

    <body>
        <div id="click">Ten Dollars </div>
        <div id="balance">
            <?php 

                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='xxxxx@xxx.com'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                echo "$row[2]";

            ?>
        </div>    

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the updatebalance.php code:

```
<?php
    include_once 'login.php';    
    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    $newBal = $_POST['ten']; 
    mysql_select_db($db_database);
    $query = "UPDATE users SET balance='$newBal' WHERE email='xxxxx@xxx.com'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result) die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());
?>
```

The following is happening:

1. When page is first loaded: "Ten Dollars" is displayed along with the balance currently in the users table for email 'xxxxx@xxx.com' - so I know there are no problems connecting to the database.
2. When I click on the "Ten Dollars": the alert pops up that says it was successful but the value is not changed in the database. The div with the balance in it just goes blank because I didn't know how to change it after "success:" ...
3. When I just run updatebalance.php and put in a number (e.g. 4) for $newBal then it properly updates in the table.
4. Also I realize that I have it so that the new value of balance would be 10, instead of previous balance + 10 but that is because I am trying to cut down places where error could be occurring.

Comment: So the problem is passing the data to the php. Can you comment out the db write and just echo $newBal?

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yeah this issue is passing the data - in this case the variable "ten." Where are you suggesting to echo $newBal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using ajax you'll have to return the variable then ouput, currently you're not so much checking that you're getting a success as you are sending the alert on a response, which would include your error code.

You can do that using a response variable (in this case the response is the variable data) which should give you some ability to see what you're returning, though if it's not updating the database that's almost certainly your failure message.

In this specific case what you're actually passing in the post variable is $_POST[0] = '10' not $_POST[ten]. You need to pass the data as an object to access it in that manner so:

```
data: { ten: ten }
```

I'd also recommend using a different name than the variable you want to access or doing something along the lines of:

```
        $(document).ready(
        function()
        {
            $("#click").click(
                function()
                {
                    var post = { ten: ""}
                    var ten = 10;
                    var post.ten = ten;
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            url:  "updatebalance.php",
                            type: "post",
                            data: post,
                            success: function(data) {

                                 document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = "";
                                 alert('it was successful');
                             }
                        }
                    );
                }
            );
        });
```

So as to avoid potential confusion and wonky behavior that ten: ten might cause due to ten being a variable name.

Edit: missed a semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Neither of your suggestions worked. Sorry, but I am still very confused. Will you elaborate on what you are doing with post.ten=ten ? All I want to do is pass the variable ten to the updatebalance.php so that I can set $newBal to that variable. Sorry for not understanding - I have tried to look up book/tutorial that deals with Ajax with Mysql databases but have not been successful at finding a good one.

Comment: Also, when I add your code - nothing happens when I click. Thanks again.

Comment: The problem is that you're trying to access the post value as an associative array but aren't giving it a name. Generally when you pass post variables in ajax you'd want to do it as an object so { name: "value" } and then would handle it in the php as $_POST['name']. In your case, without giving it a name, you're simply assigning it to the 0th position in the POST array or it's not being recognized as valid by the ajax. Here's the [manual](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), the second to last example is basically what you're trying to do and I may have added one too many var.

Comment: I understand now that you are just naming the value ten as well and then filling its value with "ten" which is 10. But nothing happens when I click now, not even the alert.

Comment: Sorry I commented before seeing the rest of your comment - I will check out that manual. Thanks!

Comment: There's a missing semi-colon on your original post(and thus my later code before my latest edit) at the line before the alert which would likely cause problems.

Comment: I followed that example that you pointed me to and got it working! Thanks! Any idea on how to refresh the balance div at the bottom of the page?

Comment: `document.getElementById("balance").innerHTML = "new html here";` or `document.getElementById("balance").html("new html here");` should do it. the variable `data`, or whatever is passed in the `success: function()` is your result object, so what the server would print out to the screen. `echo` or `print()` the new information you want in your php script and then manipulate the `data` object in your ajax function to get values from it or append it to your html through [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML) or [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

*Better way of doing this*

1. sending user email id instead of ten
2. **dataType:json** (response)
3. update query updating old column by 10 and on success returning
   json response(with error flag set to 0).
4. used jquery on **AJAX success** for updating old div (id = balance) to
   new updated balance
5. fetching  **$emailid = $_POST['emailid']** in update page for updating
   with email id

**Main page**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<script src ="js/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function()
            {
                $("#click").click(
                    function()
                    {
                        var emailid = xxxxx@xxx.com;
                        $.ajax(
                            {
                                url:  "updatebalance.php",
                                type: "post",
                                data: { emailid: xxxxx@xxx.com },
                                dataType:json,
                                success: function(data) {

                                        if(! data.error)
                                        {
                                            var old_balance = $('#balance').text();
                                            $('#balance').text() = old_balance + 10;
                                            alert('it was successful');
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            alert('Oops seems some error occured !');
                                        }

                                 }
                            }
                        );
                    }
                );
            });
 </script>


<html>

    <body>
        <div id="click">Ten Dollars </div>
        <div id="balance">
            <?php 

                $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='xxxxx@xxx.com'";
                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                echo "$row[2]";

            ?>
        </div>    

    </body>
</html>
```

**And updatebalance.php code:**

```
<?php
    include_once 'login.php';    
    $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
    $emailid = $_POST['emailid']; 
    mysql_select_db($db_database);
    $query = "UPDATE users SET balance= balance +10 WHERE email='$emailid'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if (!$result)
      echo json_encode(array('error' => 1));
    else
      echo json_encode(array('error' => 0));

?>
```

Comment: Can you explain why it is better to use emailid instead of passing ten? What if I want to end up having 10 buttons all with different amounts on them. Wouldn't it be easier to pass whichever value of the button was clicked and only have one updatebalance.php? Would there be a reason for passing both emailid and ten? Also, why is json better when I am just sending one value like this. Is it just more efficient? Thanks for answering!

Comment: I was not aware that incremment amount can differ, in this case you can use  **data: { emailid: xxxxx@xxx.com , incremment_amount:pass_from_button_click}**.And **json** is better in the sense it is clean , lightweight ,well structured .